# How would i make background image fade in?

Tags: javascript, random, background, fadein, fadeout

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function changeImg(imgNumber) {
var myImages = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];
var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);

document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
document.body.style.backgroundSize = '100% 100%'; 
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
document.body.style.backgroundAttachment= 'fixed';

}
setInterval(changeImg,5000)
window.onload = changeImg;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

I would like old picture to fade out and new picture to fade in. For some reason i cant figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: opposed to using JQuery?

Comment: Definitely agreed MathiasaurusRex. You should use JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's an easy solution with JQuery (If you're not opposed to it.)](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Ac2bs/2/)

JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(function(){
        $('.fadein a:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function(){
          $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(1000)
             .next('a').fadeIn(1000)
             .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
          2000);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="fadein">
    <a href="" id="rotatingImage1"></a>
    <a href="" id="rotatingImage2"></a>
    <a href="" id="rotatingImage3"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#rotatingImage1{background:url('http://lorempixel.com/500/501/') no-repeat;position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;}
#rotatingImage2{background:url('http://lorempixel.com/500/502/') no-repeat;position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;}
#rotatingImage3{background:url('http://lorempixel.com/500/503/') no-repeat;position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

using jquery and css, u can change the back ground.

jQuery: (in the images loaded function)

```
$('body').css('background-image', "url('" + $images[0].src + "')");
$('#wrapper').removeClass("bgFade", 700);
```

CSS:

```
.bgFade{
    background-color:#FFF;
```

}